# How would I make a Horizontal list into a vertical list

Tags: python, list, function

How would I make it so that my vowel counter returns a vertical list instead of a horizontal list. Every time I use \n it just gives me an error I have no clue what I am doing wrong, I am a beginner coder and still have problems solving this. I have tried looking for an answer and I haven't found any. Could anybody help? So instead of looking like this {'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 2, 'o': 1, 'u': 1}.

How do I make it look vertical like this

```
'a': 1 
'e': 1 
'i': 2 
'o': 1 
'u': 1
```

```
def count_vowels(string, vowels):
 string = string.casefold()
 count = {}.fromkeys(vowels, 0)

# To count the vowels
 for character in string:
     if character in count:
         count[character] += 1
 return count
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
string = "Counting all the strings"
print(count_vowels(string, vowels))
```

Comment: as a single string or with a print?

Answer (score 0):

By casting the dictionary to string and slice (or strip) the brackets should work:

```
...
string = "CoUnting All the strings"
counter = count_vowels(string)

print(*str(counter).strip('{}').split(', '), sep='\n')
#'a': 1
#'e': 1
#'i': 2
#'o': 1
#'u': 1
```

Comment: Not sure why you have to do *casting*. it's already *string*.

Comment: `count_vowels` returns a dictionary not a string

Answer (score 0):

If you want something other than Python's default formatting, then you have to do it yourself:

```
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
string = "Counting all the strings"
for k,v in count_vowels(string, vowels).items():
    print( f"{k}: {v}" )
```